# Mac Terminal link not working

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am trying to make a command line link for Sublime Text 3.

If I run `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` Sublime Text opens like normal.

I then run `sudo ln "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl`

Restart the terminal and I get this:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/subl
/usr/bin/subl
$ subl
-bash: subl: command not found
```

I also tried setting in my `.profile` `alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`

but I also get `command not found`

**EDIT:**

`/usr/bin/` is in my `PATH` as well

**EDIT2:**

I tried a restart of my computer but still doesn't work.

It seems any new alias I make won't work in my `.profile`.

I tried `ln -s "/usr/bin/mail" /usr/bin/testln` and it did work.

**EDIT3:**
I got it to work by putting an alias in `.bash_profile` instead.  I would still like to know why my `ln` doesn't work though.

Comment: Instead, say `sudo ln -sf "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl` and then try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your symlink command

```
sudo ln "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

didn't work because you both enclosed the path in quotes **and** escaped the space with a backslash. The quotes make the symlink point to the literal path

```
/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

which is not valid. You should use either

```
"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

or

```
/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

but don't combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the alias in your `.profile` file as :

```
alias subl="open -a Sublime\ Text"
```

After you do that

```
subl .
```

Should work just fine

Comment: `open -a Sublime\ Text` works in my terminal, but adding to `.profile` as an alias still gives `-bash: subl: command not found`

Comment: It seems like all new alias won't work, not just Sublime Text ones.  My existing aliases in `.profile` do work though.

Comment: Once there is a `.bash_profile`, the `.profile` will be ignored by bash. You can check what the `subl` command is by using the `type` bash builtin: `$ type subl`