# Creating `subl` alias does not actually work

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, sublimetext

After I upgraded Maverick, this all happened.

But my alias `subl` no longer works for Sublime Text Editor.

So I did this :

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

Which successfully creates the executable in my `/usr/bin/` folder where all my other executables are. However, even after restarting Terminal, it still does not respond to :

```
which subl
```

Or just :

```
subl
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac Terminal link not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909603/mac-terminal-link-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

has `"/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"` both in quotes and with an escaped space between `Sublime` and `Text`. Use one or the other.

So, first run

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/subl
```

to get rid of the old, incorrect symlink. Then, run

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

(without the escape) and you should be all set.